# Get data from a database which is in a server machine

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winForm application which will be used by more than one persone, I want to put the database in a machine server so can everyone connect to it from this application.
I'm using SqlServer database, this database will be located in a local network.
This is the connection string I use to get data from a database located in my machine

```
string con = "Data Source=MSSQL1;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=true;";
```

My question is what is the connection string that I should use to get data from database located in a machine server ?
Is it something like this ?

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately you do not give any specific information about your problem. Question is to vague, what database you will be using, what is configuration of database server. Where database server can be located, local network or over internet?

Answer (score 0):

Without any specific information nobody will be able to answer this for you, however [This Resource.](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) might help you find it for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I should try :

Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;